# Borda arredondada nos botões do Google Chrome iOS

Tags: css, ios

Atualizei recentemente meu Macbook aqui e agora todos os botões do meu site estão com a borda arredondada. Achei até que fosse algum erro de CSS, mas não, entrando no meu computador Windows está normal. Alguém sabe me dizer o que está rolando?

Comment: Posta um exemplo MCVE, porque pode ser conflito de uma ou mais regras.

Comment: Então, na verdade não, porque eu não mexi em arquivo CSS nenhum, e de uma hora para outra mudou. Como o @Karl Zillner abaixo disse é a versão. Estou acessando de um macbook meu antigo aqui e não está arredondado, já no meu macbook atual do trampo, está arredondado. Loucura.

Comment: Sim, mas as vezes pode ser uma regra que mudou também e não o border-radius em si, claro que tudo leva a crer que a resposta esta certa, mas muitas coisas podem ter mudado também, MCVE serve pra isto, pra termos certeza do que estamos respondendo, se não ficamos baseados em hipóteses.

Comment: Dando o inspect no elemento voce ve quais são os estilos padrão do navegador. Se vc pegar uma versão anterior do Chrome ele não tem o atributo **border-radius**

Comment: @KarlZillner foi um otimo chute, mas isso pode ser um problema, presumir é bom as vezes, mas não dá pra dizer sempre que é isto, ainda mais se a pergunta não contém um MCVE (leia o link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), sua resposta deve estar certa, mas as instruções que passei era para o Guilherme, MCVE é uma boa maneira de garantir boas perguntas.

Comment: Crie um arquivo .html com a linha `<button>MCVE</button>` e inspecione o elemento....eu fiz o teste aqui....e o webkit alterou o css padrão dos botões a partir dessa última versão

Comment: @KarlZillner você não entendeu o propósito do MCVE, leia o debate no Meta: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6600/3635

Comment: To ensinando a tirar a prova... no caso desse problema este é o único jeito de verificar se é este mesmo o problema.

Comment: @KarlZillner não estou falando de tirar prova, ou fazer testes, isso eu sei fazer, o problema é você entender como funciona a comunidade e entender que perguntas sem MCVE podem conter mais problemas, não tem haver com o problema em si, já falei mais de uma vez, o problema é sobre possiveis sub-problemas que podem ocorrer por não termos um MCVE para testar, veja o Debate no META, tá tudo explicado lá.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O Chrome lançou uma alteração no CSS padrão do próprio navegador.

A partir da versão que foi atualizada neste mês 
Versão 62.0.3202.94 (Versão oficial) 64 bits

O atributo **border-radius** vem por padrão com **4px** para seguintes tags:

```
input[type="button" i], 
input[type="submit" i], 
input[type="reset" i], 
input[type="file" i]::-webkit-file-upload-button, 
button {
    border-color: rgb(216, 216, 216) rgb(209, 209, 209) rgb(186, 186, 186);
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 1px 7px 2px; 
}
```

A solução é acrescentar um CSS Reset no começo do seu arquivo CSS da seguinte forma:

```
input[type="button" i], 
input[type="submit" i], 
input[type="reset" i], 
input[type="file" i]::-webkit-file-upload-button, 
button {
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: Nossa. Que malucos! Isso vai afetar diversos site.. mas enfim, obrigado pela sua resposta, espero que ajude outros com o mesmo problema que eu! Obrigado.

Comment: Pois é...tem um monte de gente que não está sabendo disso que ta com site quebrado pra Chrome no iOS atualizado....